# ORA-00932 convert and format dates and strings to calculate a range of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where the `date_one` field is of type **VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE)** and the `date_two` field is of type **DATE**.

Output for `date_one` is 29-01-2019 20:22:08 and output for `date_two` is 25-JAN-19.

I need to calculate records based on an interval of days between these two fields but I'm having a hard time with this error:

```
select field1,field2,field3 
from mytable
where 
trunc(to_date(DATE_ONE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - trunc(to_date(DATE_TWO 'DD-MM-YYYY')) > interval '15' day;
```

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER, got INTERVAL DAY
> TO SECOND
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of subtracting two dates is [a number of days](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705), unlike the result of subtracting two timestamps, which is an interval. You are currently trying to compare the number you get from that subtraction with a fixed interval - which is what the error is saying. The data types don't match and can't be implicitly converted for comparison.

You can either convert that number to an interval:

```
select field1,field2,field3
from mytable
where (trunc(to_date(DATE_ONE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - trunc(DATE_TWO)) * interval '1' day > interval '15' day;
```

or more simply just compare with the number 15:

```
select field1,field2,field3
from mytable
where trunc(to_date(DATE_ONE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) - trunc(DATE_TWO) > 15;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=254649eaf9ad4179586a3c136e7795f6)

I've changed `trunc(to_date(DATE_TWO, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))` to simply `trunc(DATE_TWO)`. Because `DATE_TWO` is already a date, when you do `to_date(DATE_TWO, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` you are implicitly converting the date to a string using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting (which seems to be DD-MON-RR), and then converting that string back to a date. As well as being a waste of effort, that may break if this is run in a session with different settings. You just need to truncate the date you already have.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution worked really well and the explanation was very clear. Thanks again

Comment: If DATE_TWO is, as you say, of type DATE, then you don't need to - and should not - apply TO_DATE to it.  TO_DATE takes a STRING and converts it to a DATE.  But DATE_TWO is _already_ a date.    Applying TO_DATE to it will force an implied TO_CHAR to get it to a string for use by TO_DATE.  Success there is a crap shoot that depends on your NLS settings.  Also, if, as you say, DATE_ONE is a varchar2, then that is a very serious design flaw that makes dealing with it problematic at every turn.